# hot to start a server through build.xml (ant) with https-connection

Tags: ant, https, wildfly, build.xml

I just configured standalone.xml of wildfly server for https-connection and everything works fine, while I start it as standalone.sh, but when I want to start it through ant build.xml it will be no any https recognised. 
So, there is a row in build.xml

```
<socker server="{jboss.bind.address}" port="8080" />
```

I believe, it have to be anyway for https connection configured, while writing port="8443" instead of helps not, server will not be started. 
Any suggestions?
In standalone.xml it looks so out:

```
<server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" proxy-address-forwarding="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="0.0.0.0">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <single-sign-on path="/"/>
            </host>
        </server>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. Starting the container from ant has nothing to do with the server configuration.

Comment: I just mean, that when I start server from /bin ./standalone.sh I can access it only through https://..., cause in my standalone.xml ssl was set up, but when I start the same server from ant, I have only http connection, so that is my question, what is to change in build.xml, to start it properly.

Comment: It depends on how you start it from ant vs how you start it from the command line.

Comment: So, i have created a new buid.xml without any former dependencies in it (before it was some extra dependencies from some demo project in it) and now it works. Anyway, thank you for conern, James.